# External content in FTS4 SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, fts4, external-contenttype

I have a VIEW `view_for_search_unit` and a FTS4 table `FTS_table_search_unit`. I inserted data from `view_for_search_unit` into the FTS table using this command:

```
INSERT INTO FTS_table_search_unit(docId, name, description)
SELECT id, name, description FROM view_for_search_unit
```

After I check data in FTS table using this:

```
SELECT *FROM FTS_table_search_unit
```

it has 1000 perfect records(I use fake data). However, when I use the `MATCH`
function in FTS:

```
SELECT * FROM FTS_table_search_unit WHERE FTS_table_search_unit MATCH 's*'
```

I retrieve 1000 records but all columns in the result are `NULL`. What is the problem? I can't understand because there is data in `FTS_table_search_unit`.

Comment: Thank Simon, because my English is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try docid instead of *:

```
SELECT docid FROM FTS_table_search_unit 
WHERE FTS_table_search_unit 
MATCH 's*'
```

or

```
SELECT v.* FROM FTS_table_search_unit s
INNER JOIN view_for_search_unit v ON s.docid = v.id
WHERE FTS_table_search_unit MATCH 's*';
```